# Disable horizontal swipe for UIPageViewController (except at edges)

Tags: ios, ios8, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I essentially want a UITextView to scroll vertically but not ever be able to accidentally scroll the UIPageViewController when the gesture occurs within the UITextView.

I do still want the page turning gesture to work along the edges though:

[image]

Comment: Are you UIPageViewControllers setup to scroll horizontally as depicted in your diagram? If so, why would the UITextView vertical scroll interfere?

Comment: Pages are set to turn horizontally. You're right, the vertical UITextView scroll doesn't necessarily interfere if the gesture is clearly a vertical one. In use however, I find that it is accidentally turning the page more than I would like.

Comment: if you just want the edges to swipe, you can try adding a tap gesture to the UITextView and disable the UIPageViewConroller

Comment: I still want the page to scroll, but only when panning from the edges. Adding a tap gesture did not seem to solve it for me.